# numpy - multiplay only if

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a big issue here, i'm working with numpy and trying to understand it better, but i hit small issues on the road to my goal.

here is my code.

```
product_test = []
product_test.append({
    'min-dkk' : 149.9,
    'min-procent' : 100.0,
    'max-dkk' : 249.9,
    'max-procent' : 0.0,
    'cost-price' : 400.0
})
product_test.append({
    'min-dkk' : 150.1,
    'min-procent' : 0.0,
    'max-dkk' : 0.0,
    'max-procent' : 10,
    'cost-price' : 1000.0
})

product_test.append({
    'min-dkk' : 25.0,
    'min-procent' : 5000.0,
    'max-dkk' : 100.0,
    'max-procent' : 0.0,
    'cost-price' : 10.0
})

# print(product_test)
list_product = None
for test in product_test:
    if list_product is None:
        list_product = np.array([[test['min-dkk'],test['min-procent'],test['max-dkk'],test['max-procent'],test['cost-price']]])
    else:
        product_price_data = np.array([[test['min-dkk'],test['min-procent'],test['max-dkk'],test['max-procent'],test['cost-price']]])
        list_product = np.vstack((list_product, product_price_data))

print('')
print(list_product)

list_product[:,0] += 0.0 if list_product[:,0] == 0 else list_product[:,4]
list_product[:,1] = 0.0 if (list_product[:,4] + ((list_product[:,4]/100) * list_product[:,1])) == list_product[:,4] else (list_product[:,4] + ((list_product[:,4]/100) * list_product[:,1]))
list_product[:,2] += 0.0 if list_product[:,2] == 0 else list_product[:,4]
list_product[:,3] = 0.0 if (list_product[:,4] + ((list_product[:,4]/100) * list_product[:,3])) == list_product[:,4] else (list_product[:,4] + ((list_product[:,4]/100) * list_product[:,3]))
```

if i run this on only 1 row in my numpy array its working fine, if i run this code, i will get the error

```
list_product[:,0] += 0.0 if list_product[:,0] == 0 else 

list_product[:,4]
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

my idea is i want to multiplay fields based on a value if the value are greater then 0 (zero) and its work fine when i do it on only one array row but when i work with multi rows i get this error, and i have trying to read up on it and i'm not intresset to return "True / False" i want to do my math if its diffred from zero becures the price rules can be postive or negativ in our dynamic range.

Comment: `if` is a python operation that only works with a scaler true/false value.  Your equality test produces boolean array, more than one true/false values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent in numpy would be:

```
list_product[:,0] += (list_product[:,0] != 0) * list_product[:,4]
```

The condition is now evaluated to an array of type boolean, cast to the type of list_product (1 for true, 0 for false) then multiplied with the array you might want to add.

Comment: thanks a lot, thats what i need to get it fixed and thanks for explanation